# Are class function arguments better than class variables in C++ for computationally intensive functions?

Tags: c++, matlab

I am implementing a class that will perform a computation on a set of images. However, there are some parameters to the algorithm. I am also planning to build a MATLAB interface to use the class and make the computations possible by using the MATLAB.

I would like to know how to better design the class and whether it is better to pass the parameters when calling the member function or having them stored inside the class as class attributes. Here is a high level design of my class in C++:

```
class ComputationClass {
  public:
    ComputationClass(InfrastructureClass cl);
    std::vector<float> computation_algorithm_1(std::vector<float> data);
    std::vector<float> computation_algorithm_2(std::vector<float> data);

  private:
    InfrastructureClass cl_;

    float computation_part_for_both_functions(std::vector<float> data);
};
```

The class requires an object of another class which performs a part of the computation as an API. I do not have access to the other class, I am just doing some requests, etc.

Now, both computation algorithms (`computation_algorithm_1` and `computation_algorithm_2`) have a set of parameters that are common. For example the:

- `size_t max_allowed_iterations`
- `float stopping_criterion`
- `int power_of_Q` (the power to raise one of the algorithms parameters

But the second algorithm has two extra parameters, `float step` which defines how much each iteration changes the outcome, and `bool preprocess` that defines if there is a need for preprocessing. The algorithms are quite different one from another, but they have some common functionality by using the `float computation_part_for_both_functions()` function. They follow the same idea, but they have some different steps.

1. One choice is to implement the algorithm parameters as class variables (where the constructor will initialize them in case none is provided) and I also need to have some `set` and `get` functions. The user (either from C++ or the MATLAB API) will have to `set` the parameters before calling the algorithm.
2. The other choice makes the functions to accept many more parameters. Simplifies the class, but the functions may receive large amounts of parameters. Also, most algorithm parameters are optional and they have some default value.

The problem is that the parameter list that these functions receive might change in the near future and a few more parameters might be added.

Edit: I was thinking of providing some `public` nested class or `struct` so that I can pass the arguments that I need to the function, because you cannot skip default arguments in C++, but I do not know if this a good design at all.

Comment: Have you considered having one class per algorithm?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have not considered that yet because the goal was to have only one algorithm but we found an alternation to that algorithm that we want to test. The algorithms have some common functionality at some steps which might be abstracted by having some private functions. I will edit to give more details.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title:
I would say it does not matter—from a computational perspective—if you use function arguments or class fields. Both are equally efficient.

There are, however, edge cases where one or the other has advantages.

1. If the functions are recursive, obviously duplicating the parameters is not necessary and adds some minor overhead. Here, class fields may be appropriate.
2. If you access the parameters a lot, accessing fields of a class requires one additional indirection (access `this` on the stack and then access `this->parameter` *vs.* access `parameter` on the stack). Here, function parameters may be better.

In both edge cases, it only makes a *measurable* difference if the core algorithm is very fast, and the main computation time is used doing recursion or accessing parameters.

If in doubt, I would prefer function parameters, as these are more intuitive. (This is of course completely subjective. But I'm also used to functional programming as well as R, where parameters are very rarely set in a separate state variable.)

One may consider using class fields (or a separate `struct parameters`) if you have dozens of parameters. Then, function signatures may look ugly:

```
return_type algorithm(int parameter1, double parameter2, int parameter3, int parameter4, int parameter5, double parameter6, int parameter7, int parameter8, bool parameter9, double parameter10, bool parameter11, double parameter12, int parameter13, double parameter14, int parameter15, int parameter16, bool parameter17, double parameter18, int parameter19, double parameter20, int parameter21, int parameter22, bool parameter23, double parameter24)
```

However, if you use class fields, the same set of parameters are defined somewhere. Thus, one may as well re-format the signature:

```
return_type algorithm(
    int parameter1,
    double parameter2,
    int parameter3,
    int parameter4,
    …)
```

Another point to consider (from a code maintenance perspective) is if you pass the parameters to various sub-routines. Then, having a compact `parameters` object might be definitely better.

From a user interface perspective, it is definitely more convenient and intuitive for the user to pass the parameters to the function. However, this does not prevent you from setting fields in the class. But I would add this only of really necessary.

As you said in your comment, many parameters have optional values; and it is impossible in C++ to define an arbitrary sub-set of optional parameters.
As your function is to be called from Matlab, I would then simply suggest to write a simple wrapper in Matlab which handles all optional parameters, and then calls the C++ function with the complete set.

Comment: I am thinking that what you are suggesting (e.g. use function parameters) would be the better case. I do not care about the computational efficiency at that point, but I think its more intuitively to use it that way. 

The only difficulty that I am having is that the functions will have a large parameter list of default arguments and it will be harder to set them because there is no way to skip a default argument in C++. Therefore, if you want to provide the third default agument you have to set the second as well. Providing a `struct` of the parameters is similar to implement them in class.

Comment: If the class is used only in Matlab, than why not provide a wrapper in Matlab which supports all the optional arguments, and calls the C++ function with the complete set? However, if the list of parameters is huge, a separate `parameter` struct might actually be more readable in the C++ code.